# How to call child component function in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to call component function from the sibling component and I decided to make it with parent component and refs.
Here is my parent component **SMS-Registration.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import PhoneNumber from './Sms/PhoneNumber';
import VerificationCode from './Sms/VerificationCode';

class SmsRegistration extends Component {
  state = {
    confirm: false,
    phone: '',
    content: null,
  };

  setToTrue = () => {
    this.setState({
      confirm: true,
    });
  };

  resendCode = () => {
    this.child.testFunc();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {!this.state.confirm ? (
          <PhoneNumber
            onRef={ref => (this.child = ref)}
            setToTrue={this.setToTrue}
          />
        ) : (
          <VerificationCode
            resend={this.resendCode}
          />
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default SmsRegistration;
```

First child component **PhoneNumber.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {ButtonComponent} from 'components/common';


export default class PhoneNumber extends Component {


  testFunc = () => {
    console.log('test func click');
  };

  setToTrue = () => {
    this.props.setToTrue();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        // this is custom button component which receives 2 params (title, callback)
        <ButtonComponent
                buttonCaption="Set to True"
                onTouch={this.setToTrue}
              />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and the second child component **Verification.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {ButtonComponent} from 'components/common';

export default class VerificationCode extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  resendCode = () => {
    this.props.resend();
  };


  render() {
    const changeValue = (value) => {
      this.getData(value);
    };
    return (
      <View>
        <ButtonComponent
            buttonCaption="Resend Code"
            onTouch={this.resendCode}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I try to run method from the **PhoneNumber.js** it says that this.child is undefined. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: I'd question the need for this--using a ref for this purpose ul can indicate that state or functionality is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the PhoneNumber component is not yet initialize. Since you have a condition the confirm state the PhoneNumber component and the this.child will not be initialize until it becomes true. That's why you receive an error of undefined.

Comment: but PhoneNumber comes first and than VerificationCode appear, but I think I get your point, I think it should be rendered both in the same time

Comment: Yes it  comes first, but it is not rendered because of your condition. It will be rendered only when "confirm" state becomes true.

Comment: Maybe its better if you add another props for PhoneNumber like a 'visible' props so that you can pass there whether you want to show the PhoneNumber component or not. And you dont need that condition "this.state.confirm"